# How to show options in tkinter option menu when the options are too long

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I have an optionmenu in tkinter that lists a variety of options. The width of my optionmenu is not great enough to show the full options, however, as they are quite long. Currently, the optionmenu (when not open) shows the middle characters of each line, however I would like for it to show the first few letters that can fit instead. Is there any way to do this?

Here is the code I have:

```
choices = ['1. Reflectance - Original', 
        '2. Reflectance - Original without Negative Values', 
        '3. Reflectance - Normalised',
        '4. Reflectance - Normalised without Negative Values', 
        '5. Absorbance - Original', 
        '6. Absorbance - Original without Negative Values', 
        '7. Absorbance - Normalised',
        '8. Absorbance - Normalised without Negative Values', 
        '9. Recreated Image', 
        '10. New Image']

drop_down_var.set(choices[0])
drop_down_menu = OptionMenu(root, drop_down_var, *choices, command=__update_data)
drop_down_menu.configure(highlightthickness=0, width=9)
```

So for example, I would like the collapsed menu to show '1. Refl...' (there don't need to be dots) instead of 'ance - Orig'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your original list, you can do a list comprehension while passing to the `OptionMenu`:

```
drop_down_var.set(choices[0][:7])
drop_down_menu = OptionMenu(root, drop_down_var, *[i[:7] for i in choices], command=__update_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to keep the full options, but just show the first parts when the option menu was collapsed. The solution I ended up using was to change the configure part to:

```
drop_down_menu.configure(highlightthickness=0, width=6, anchor='w', padx=15)
```

i.e. adding an anchor and some padding. Hope this helps anyone with the same problem!